# SvelteKit Routing: Navigation to index.html results in null route.id

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm not sure if this is a SvelteKit bug or invalid usage. I'm serving a built SvelteKit app out of S3 using signed cookies for auth. When the user navigates directly to an index.html page for some path, the page loads properly but the `route.id` is null, which is causing several dependencies we have to fail as they rely on hashing the `route.id` for various reasons.

Is this a bug in SvelteKit or in valid usage? In either case, is there a way to programmatically set the route.id? I believe that it is a read-only store so I imagine not.

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure you are not supposed to specify `index.html` directly, just about any server will allow omitting it. Might still be considered a bug, though...